# Number of ways of distributing n identical objects among r groups of increasing size

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am looking for a formula giving the number of ways n identical objects can be distributed in r groups (n>=r) of increasing size. Can this be solved using Bell numbers?

Comment: Do you allow groups to be empty?

Comment: There are only trivial cases as 0,a1,a2,a3, ... 0,0,a2,a3, ... Note that a1<a2<a3 ...

Comment: Do the groups have to be strictly increasing? If so, and you do not allow an empty group, you need $n \ge \frac 12r(r+1)$.  You can start by putting those objects in the bins, then you need a nondecreasing composition of the rest

Comment: Actually not strictly increasing. Two consecutive groups can have similar sizes.